# Saving NDVI TIFF file as txt file in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, dem, ndvi, text

I have to use elevation data (dem.tif) and NDVI data (ndvi.tif) as covariates for regression kriging and I want both these files as txt files.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the ([Raster to ASCII](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/raster-to-ascii.htm)) tool.

ArcTool Box go Conversion > From Raster > Raster to ASCII

Then locate your input raster and click on output location, then under Save as Type select second option "File".

Comment: Thanks Moh. Could you please also clarify me to use elevation from dem and NDVI as covariates 
1. Do I need to project them first
2. Do I need to resample them to same cell size
before converting them to txt file

Comment: @AhmedShabir If this answer solve your question. Please mark it as accepted. For your other questions please post them in new question.